# 404 Error accessing Okta IdP metadata via URL

Tags: saml-2.0, okta

I created SAML 2.0 template in Okta and copied metadata URL in my application configuration. However I am getting 404 error . I also tried accessing URL via browser which did give me 404 error. Has anyone had this issue? I was trying to search it on internet and have not seen any solution. Wondering if something is wrong with the setup. Surprisingly downloading metadata in a file and using File based metadata configuration works fine. Any guess what could be happening here?

When using URL I also see xml parser exceptions.

```
    2016-11-02 13:22:48,905 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - XML Parsing Error
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 3; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide me the metadata url that you are using? Please make sure that you are obtaining the metadata url in Okta by going to Your SAML app -> Sign On tab -> and under "View Setup Instructions" there is Identity Provider Metadata link. You need to copy that link. It can be seen below as well.

[image]

Link looks like https://org-name.okta.com/app/cxk5x6wkxxxxxxx0x7/sso/saml/metadata

In case if you have obtained metadata file url via same method and resemble above example url then please can you provide that?